# ui tabs ver 2.7 jQuery error when i switching from jQuery 1.1.3 to jQuery 1.3.2

Tags: jquery, user-interface, tabs

I have a problem , i'm using jQuery plugin from  http://www.stilbuero.de/jquery/tabs/  , plugin for tabs and  that enable history support for Tabs  ui tabs ver 2.7, i switched from jQuery 1.1.3 to jQuery 1.3.2  and it's given the error in firebug **uncaught exception: Syntax error , unrecognized expression: [@href$="#fragment-1"]** , the plugin is working fine , but i don't like this error , what can be ... Sorry for my English , and thx :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The @ symbol was deprecated in the move from jquery 1.2.6 to 1.3.

```
[@href$="#fragment-1"]
```

should just be

```
[href$="#fragment-1"]
```

You should probably make the move to the UI tabs plugin too if you're changing your jquery version. Get it from the [jqueryui project](http://jqueryui.com/)

Comment: does not support history the new version